# Does anyone have an example of a unit test for a Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Has anyone successfully written a unit test for a Razor view in ASP.Net MVC 3? I've been trying to create one but keep banging my head against various Null Reference exceptions.